# Using "anything" instead of "something"

Tags: pronouns

It would be correct to use "something" un the sentence like:

> She has rung you up to tell that she has found out something about it.

I'd better put "anything" instead of using "something" in order to convey the meaning of the following sentence correctly:

> I wanted to find out anything about him.

Wouldn't it?

Comment: I've changed your tag: *anything* and *something* aren't gerunds but compounds of *any* and *some* with *thing*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. *Anything* in that sense is a [negative polarity item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item), so it can only occur in negative or interrogative contexts.

You can say

> I didn't find out anything about him. (negative)

or

> Did you find out anything about him? (interrogative)

but not

> *I found out anything about him

[There is another meaning of *anything* which is not limited to negative contexts, where it means *something, it doesn't matter what*. For example:

> Find out **anything** about him!

But that's usually inconsistent with a past affirmative.]